# integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2(1+x^2)}dx$ with Plancherel

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I should calculate the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2(1+x^2)}dx$$ with the Plancherel Formula $\| f\|_2 = (2\pi)^{1/2} \| \mathcal{F}(f) \|_2 $ where $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is the fourier transformation of $f$ and we use the norm in $ L^2(\mathbb{R}) $. I began with trying to find a function, which is either the fourier transformation or the inverse fourier transformation of the square root of the function above, so $\frac{\sin(x)}{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}$. But it seems quite hard to calculate the fourier function (or the inverse one). Is there a trick in this exercise?

Comment: Is the solution using plancherel formula compulsory? As there are many other solutions to this without using that.

Comment: I found more than one solution on the internet, but we have to solve it with Plancherel... :(

Comment: One can also apply Plancherel's theorem to the $L^{2}(\mathbb {R} )$ inner product of two functions - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem .
For example, $f(x)=\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Comment: I can't help but feel we should split the integrand as $\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}-\frac{\sin^2x}{1+x^2}$ since the first term's integral on $\Bbb R$ is famous, then only do the second part by Plancherel.